# Boolean algebra: Why is $(x'\lor y')(x' \lor y)\equiv x' \lor y'y$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image]

Perhaps they've skipped some steps?

Comment: That's [distributivity law of $\vee$ over $\wedge$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws), like "factorising" the common "$x'\vee$" part out of your two pairs of parentheses.